# How to generate PDF document from the HTML template on Google Firebase?

Tags: firebase, pdf-generation, html-to-pdf

What would be the best solution for generating PDF files from the HTML template on Google Firebase?

I would like to use [html-pdf-chrome plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf-chrome), but I'm not sure how to configure it. Are there better solutions and do I need to upgrade my Firebase plan to enable 3rd party solutions?
I'm on the free Spark plan currently.

Comment: did you found an answer, does it apply to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63862921/pdf-generation-on-firebase-what-options-does-somone-have or?

Comment: @Xanlantos your link is dead. I didn't found the solution for this.

Comment: I found a solution for my problem but using https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/0.1/getting-started/ so not for an HTML template, maybe that helps you anyway. Also take a look at this post: https://medium.com/@arnotixe/generate-a-pdf-with-google-cloud-functions-triggered-by-firestore-db-changes-5d626f066a77

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of these extensions based on your requirements:

- https://extensions.dev/extensions/pdfplum/http-pdf-generator
- https://extensions.dev/extensions/pdfplum/firestore-pdf-generator

disclaimer: I'm the author of these extensions